# Standardized Link Type for Address

Tags: html, hyperlink, street-address

Is there any sort of standardized way to format links to addresses? Emails have `href='mailto:[email]'` and most phones (and Skype) support the `href='tel:[phone#]'`, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of standardized practice for addresses, as opposed to just linking back to a specific provider like Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest standard is for [the geo: scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) which lets you specify latitude and longitude.

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">Wikimedia Headquarters</a>
```

Comment: Awesome. Not ideal, but good enough for now, thanks for the quick response!